# Bluetooth headphones missing beggining of sounds

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I am using a pair of Bluetooth Jabra Elite 45h with Windows 10 and I noticed recently that it misses the beginning of sounds. It is specially noticeable because I am doing some language courses, and if it is a short audio, I can barely hear it, as the sound only starts (or it starts really low, I am not 100% sure) after about 1 second.

It is hard to notice the problem during "normal" use, like in videos or music, because if it is a continuous sound it plays normally. I also used the playback test from Windows, that rings on the left ear and then on the right, and I can barely hear the left one.

Is there any configuration I can set on Windows or is it a inherent problem of Bluetooth?

Comment: It's probably an inherent problem of some sort of power saving of the headphones that may or may not be possible to disable (very likely not).

Comment: You might have independent volume controls for your headset versus windows. If you turn up the volume in Windows it can create some minimum level of "noise" that stops  the device power saving from letting it go to sleep. I had a cheap Bluetooth speaker that did this.